# How to filter by a date range without time components in an SQL statement

Tags: sql-server

Example query

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE New_ActualDate >= @fromdate AND New_ActualDate <= @todate

q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromdate", calFrom.SelectedDate);
q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todate", calTo.SelectedDate);
```

When I examine the parameter values they are:

@fromdate = '01/08/2016 00:00:00'
@todate = '31/08/2016 00:00:00'

The issue i'm seeing is that any orders from yesterday (31st August) are missing from the report.

Do I need to also set the time in this example?

Comment: if the column `New_ActualDate` contains time, change your query to `AND New_ActualDate < dateadd(day, 1, @todate)`

Comment: have you got sql 2012, can you CAST or CONVERT to DATE type?

Answer (score 4):

The "trick" is to use tomorrow's date and change `<=` to `<`:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE New_ActualDate >= @fromdate AND New_ActualDate < @todatePlusOne

q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromdate", calFrom.SelectedDate);
q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todatePlusOne", calTo.SelectedDate.AddDays(1));
```

---

Note that the `@todate` = `31/08/2016 23:59:59` workaround is not recommended: You miss stuff happening between `23:59:59` and `00:00:00`. Trying to get the point which is *exactly* one minimal unit smaller than `00:00:00` is hard, since it depends on the exact data type and you have to take rounding into account. If you are interested in the details, there's a blog article on that topic:

- [Aaron Bertrand: Bad habits to kick: mis-handling date/range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: To make your answer not just good, but perfect, explain why keeping the date and setting the time to something like `23:59:59` is a bad idea.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: It's also a valid solution, but (a) it's more work and (b) you might miss stuff between `23:59:59.000` and `23:59:59.999` (or even `23:59:60` in case of leap seconds?). Are there any other drawbacks I've missed?

Comment: Taken from [Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries): the exact value depends on the type. For `datetime` it is `23:59:59.997`. For `smalldatetime` it will round up. For `datetime2(7)` you need `23:59:59.9999999` and so on. The comment is too small to explain it properly, you'd better put it in the answer. So, yes, you might miss something or include things that you shouldn't.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: Done. Feel free to edit if I forgot anything.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given will work, and is a good way of working around combined date/time fields. However, it might be worth you (or other readers) understanding an alternative solution - why work around things when you don't need to?

SQL Server supports a `date` datatype, which does exactly what you would expect: it stores a date only, no timestamp. This has some size benefits, and also helps you avoid needing to write messy queries to work around the timestamp.

If the `New_ActualDate` column is only a date, it could (and I would argue *should*) use `date` rather than `datetime` or `datetime2`. You could then pass just the date part of your parameters to it, and your query would work as you were initially hoping.

Answer (score 0):

I think the BETWEEN syntax is nice and clean.  In order to use it we have an extension called `.EndOfDay()`.

So I would likely write this in the following way:

**C# Extension (any language should support something similar)**

```
public static DateTime EndOfDay(this DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, 0, 0, 0, dateTime.Kind).AddDays(1).AddMinutes(-1);
        }
```

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE New_ActualDate BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate
```

**Parameters**

```
q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromdate", calFrom.SelectedDate);
q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todate", calTo.SelectedDate.EndOfDay());
```